# Can a dijit dialog box be closed outside module it was created in

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an application with a main page that calls different tools when the user clicks nodes on a dijit tree. The dijit Tree is located within the leading content pane and when the user clicks a tool node a module get created in the center content pane with the tool like this:

Main Page:
Tools
   Mark Ticket
   Find Ticket

When the user clicks the Mark Ticket link the Mark Ticket Module gets created, and
Within the Mark Ticket Module another module gets created that is a non-modal dijit dialog.

When the user clicks the Find Ticket link the Mark Ticket Module is destroyed and and the Find Ticket module is created.
If the non-modal dialog is left open, is there anyway I can close it when the user clicks the Find Ticket link?

I've been trying to get a reference to the dialog on the main page through a reference to the MarkTicket module:

-- the Mark Ticket module is created when link is created
DAMT = new MarkTicket({}, "tool");

DAMT.myDialog  /*The dialog box gets created within the Mark Ticket module and is referenced within the module with a 
               data-dojo-attach-point="myDialog"*/

I've also tried referencing the dialog box on the main page using:
this.myDialog

but thats not working either

Thanks

Comment: I've managed to hide the dialog in the destroy method of the MarkTicket widget:
destroy: function () {
            MT.myDialog.hide();
        }
unfortunately after this I cant recreate any of the modules

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Dialog's `destroy` method in the Module's `destroy` method (perhaps after `hide` is called).

Some code snippets may allow for a better answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I hid the dialog in the destroy function of the Mark Ticket widget.  I also needed to call the superclass destroy method in the custom method (this is what was giving me problems recreating the module:

```
 destroy: function () {
            MT.myDialog.hide();//MT is the dialog widget
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },
```